# Setting string to '\0'

Tags: c

I'm looking at some existing code and added a few printf lines.  There's a string cp "TZ=test"

```
cp = strchr(str, '=');
printf("Text: %s\n",cp);
printf("Text cp+1: %s\n",cp+1);
*cp = '\0';
printf("Text: %s\n",cp);
printf("Text cp+1: %s\n",cp+1);
```

the output is:

```
Text: =test
Text c+1: test
Text:
Text c+1: test
```

I understand the first two tests but why does the fourth one print "test" even though *cp was set to '\0' right before?

Comment: What did you expect it to print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, C doesn't know what string is, it only knows where it ends, so it prints from the pointer that you give it.

```
    [=test\0]
1:   ^start here
          ^ end at \0
2:    ^start here
          ^ end at \0

    [\0test\0]
3:   ^start here, it's \0, so stop
4:     ^start here
           ^ end at \0
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're printing *cp+1.

Here's what cp looked like before:

=test
^^^^^^^^

and here's after

test
^^^^^^^^

You only overwrote the first character.

Answer (score 2):

It is irrelevant whether you set `cp[0]` to '\0'. You are printing `cp+1` which is still "test".

Answer (score 2):

Because you are only setting the first character of the string to `\0`. The rest of the memory is untouched. So printing from `*cp + 1` begins printing from `Test` and not from `\0Test`.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a character to `\0` will terminate the string before it at this point since `\0` is the string end character in C.

Anything after it is not affected by it, so it is a great way to avoid allocating more memory when splitting a string since you can just replace the separator with `\0` and then use the original pointer to the beginning of the string to get the first part, and `sep + 1` to get the second part.